# returning swift protocol associated type in multiple methods

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

Coming from a java/kotlin background I am trying to get my head around swift protocols with associated types. Why does the following snippet fail to compile with error: "Type ViewFactoryImpl does not conform to protocol ViewFactory" and what would be the solution?

```
protocol ViewFactory  {
    associatedtype V: View
    func createSomeView() -> V
    func createAnotherView() -> V
}

class ViewFactoryImpl: ViewFactory {
    
    func createSomeView() ->  some View {
        return ViewA()
    }
    
    func createAnotherView() ->  some View {
        return ViewB()
    }
}
```

By playing around i was able to compile by defining the following instead

```
protocol ViewFactory  {
    associatedtype V1: View
    associatedtype V2: View
    func createSomeView() -> V1
    func createAnotherView() -> V2
}
```

I do not understand the issue. I thought the associated type is defined for the entire protocol and can be used in multiple methods. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you came up with by playing around is exactly what you need

As mentioned elsewhere, the main issue with your first protocol is that you're enforcing `createSomeView()` `createAnotherView()` both return the same type. While `ViewA()` and `ViewB()` are both candidates for `V`, since they conform to `View` they are still different types, and therefore cannot BOTH be `V` in a given object.

By defining both `V1` and `V2`, you allow for each function to return a different type, or the same type, it's all acceptable. By making both `V1` and `V2` require `View` conformance, you allow for the `some View` syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reactions although I was definitely not clear enough regarding my intention. The idea behind this was to play around with solutions for decoupling navigation for a larger app with several modules. defining associated types for each destination seems a bit overkill to me. Using AnyView would help to erase type issues but might be costly perfomance wise. Maybe the best solution for this case would be to stick to UIKit for navigation. this way at least I would be able to manipulate navigation state outside the view

Answer (score 2):

1. Each `associatedtype` refers to one type.
2. `ViewA` and `ViewB` are not the same type.
3. `some` does not turn them both into the same type.

And even if they were backed by the same type, you can't use multiple opaque return types to match a single associated type.

```swift
protocol ViewFactory  {
  associatedtype View: SwiftUI.View
  func createSomeView() -> View
  func createAnotherView() -> View
}

// Type 'ViewFactoryImpl' does not conform to protocol 'ViewFactory'
class ViewFactoryImpl: ViewFactory {
  func createSomeView() -> some View {
    ViewA()
  }

  func createAnotherView() -> some View {
    ViewA()
  }
}
```

The closest you can get to that is to use a type alias. It carries semantic meaning but does nothing to obscure the underlying types.

```swift
class ViewFactoryImpl: ViewFactory {
  typealias View = ViewA

  func createSomeView() -> View {
    ViewA()
  }

  func createAnotherView() -> View {
    ViewA()
  }
}
```